# derivative with a constraint

Tags: analysis

Consider a function $f(x)=\frac{a}{x^2}$ where $\frac{a}{x}=1+\varepsilon$.

The derivative of $f(x)$ is of course $f'(x)=\frac{-2a}{x^3}=g(x)$.

If we rewrite $f(x)$ as $f(x)=\frac{1+\varepsilon}{x}$, the derivative is given by $f'(x)=\frac{-(1+\varepsilon)}{x^2}=h(x)$.

If $\varepsilon=0$, it follows that $g(x)=\frac{-2}{x^2}$ whereas $h(x)=\frac{-1}{x^2}$.

Why does such a difference appear and which is correct(the latter seems to be correct)?

Comment: You forgot to take into account $\varepsilon'(x)$.

Comment: As defined, $\epsilon $ isn't a constant, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Note that $\varepsilon = \frac ax - 1$, which means that it has a non-zero derivative with respect to $x$ (namely $-a/x^2$). So your calculation of $h(x)$ *ought* to be, using the differentiation rule for fractions:
$$
h(x) = f'(x) = \frac{(1+\varepsilon)'\cdot x - (1+\varepsilon)\cdot x'}{x^2}\\
= \frac{x\varepsilon' - 1 - \varepsilon}{x^2}\\
= \frac{x(-a/x^2) - 1 - (a/x - 1)}{x^2}\\
= \frac{-\frac ax - 1 - \frac ax + 1}{x^2}\\
= \frac{-2a}{x^3} = g(x)
$$

Comment: @MyGlasses You're right. Fixed it.